# How can I make my custom policy recognize the token generated by my Azure AD B2C user flow?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

My current application has an Azure AD B2C user flow for log in and I created a custom policy to change some details about the account. The custom policy is working well when tested in the Azure, but in the application, the token generated by the user flow for log in is not recognized as a valid one when entering the custom policy, and the token returned by the custom policy is not recognized  as a valid one when returning back to the application. For creating the custom policy I used the same steps as the official documentation from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

I try to modify the IdentityExperienceFramework app but almost any change resulted in a "Invalid username or password." error when trying to login to modify the account in the custom policy. Is there a way that the IdentityExperienceFramework app will recognized token issued by another app in the directory and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot [mix and match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64915324/azure-ad-b2c-combine-custom-flows-with-built-in-user-flows) user flows and custom policies.

If you create a user in a user flow, you will not be able to log in as that user in a custom policy.